# Failed to create syimbolic link error

Tags: symbolic-link

When I execute a .sh file, I get this error:

`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/lib/ld-lsb.so.3': File exists`

How can I solve it? I'tried to give a look to similar posts, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this file [is not from Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=ld-lsb.so.3), so you can remove it with

```
sudo rm /lib/ld-lsb.so.3
```

and then retry.